# using preg replace to format urls

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a regex that takes a string like a bbcode and transforms it to a html link. It work fine. but, I want to make it detect the type of the link (internal/external) to decide whether to strictly use the absolute (external) url like `http://extsite.com/category/keyword/` or use the part of the internal url like `category/keyword/` and append it to a predefined url like `$url . category/keyword/`

The regex is as follows:

```
preg_replace('/\[([^\]]+)\]\[([^\]"]+)\]/i', '<a href="$2">$1</a>', $text)
```

Any suggestion will be very appreciated.

Comment: how do you define an internal link? is it any link that doesn't start with `http://` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, I will assume that any link that starts with http:// (or any similar protocol, e.g. ftp://) is an absolute link. Any other link will be considered a relative link (and will be prefixed by $url)

```
// replace absolute links
$text = preg replace ('/\[([^\]]+)\]\[([A-Za-z]+:\/\/[^\]"]+)\]/i',
                      '<a href="$2">$1</a>', $text )


// replace all remaining (relative) links
// $url must have a tailing slash '/'
$text = preg replace ('/\[([^\]]+)\]\[([^\]"]+)\]/i',
                      '<a href="'.$url.'$2">$1</a>', $text )
```

Comment: ok I have already done it but with https? instead of [A-Za-z]+ but your example seems to be better as mine doesn't support protocols other than http and https. thanks.

Comment: How about the `//` relative protocol? It still counts as an external link `//google.com` is a valid external URL.

Comment: @Truth: the regexp can be modified as such. As I said, it depends on the definition of "external" and "internal" links